# How to return a parameter in an alert box

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a drop-down list in a form that asks the user to pick between two teams. I would like the alert-box to show what team they picked after submitting the form.

**HTML**

```html
                <form id="form-add-participant">
                   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                  <div class="container my-2">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Involvement</label>
                            <select type="select" id="select-team" class="form-control" name="involvement" required>
                              <option value="" selected disabled>Select Team</option>
                              <option value="Participant">Team Blue</option>
                              <option value="Organizer">Team Red</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-right mt-4">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-add" data-involvement="'+data.involvement+'">Add</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

**Javascript**

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#form-add-participant', function() {
      var involvement  = $(this).attr('data-involvement');
      $.ajax({
            url: "students/team/add",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
              if (data.success === true) {
                alert(involvement + " member has been added!");
                location.reload();
              }
              else {
                alert(data.error);
              }
            }
          });
            return false;
    });
```

The alert shows " 'undefined' member has been added!", so it weren't able to successfully get the said information from the form, although I checked the dev console and I was about to successfully send the parameters for "team" through the XHR.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything that says "member has been added!" ?

Comment: @zfrisch apologies, I copy pasted an older version of my code, edited it now. It's in the alert(involvement + "memberh as been added!");

<javascript> part of the code

Comment: That is not pure html, but looks like a templating language. Can you tell us what templating language you are using? It looks like the data-involvement attribute value is not being properly set (thus undefined). data is not even defined, is that passed into the template ?

Comment: So is `$(this).attr('data-involvement');` undefined??? Only way that would be possible

Comment: @epascarello yeah, it's showing undefined in the alert-box.

Do you know how can I return either Team Blue or Team Red (as selected by the user) to the alert box?

Comment: My guess it has to do with how you are setting that attribute. The HTML mark-up looks like you are using something to build it so my guess is your code is broken there. `data-involvement="'+data.involvement+'"` <-- not sure what is up with that

Comment: And if you are using data attributes, use jQuery's data() method

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer was so far removed from the question presented that it is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `involvement` variable to:

```js
var involvement  = $("#select-team option:selected").text();
```

or

```js
var involvement  = $("#select-team option:selected").val();
```

depending what you want to show in the alert, the text inside the option or it's value.